# How to update file write permission in Git

Tags: git, version-control

### Background

I have a config file for SSH checked into a repository that is cloned by systems that run automated tests. I am running Linux (so are my target machines), and I accidentally checked the first version of the file in with a permissions field of 664. OpenSSH rejects the config file because of the group write permission.

I need to change the file permission bits to 644 and commit that change, but Git doesn't recognize the file as changed.

### Question

How can I update the file write permissions in the repository?

### Resolution Attempts

- git add config --force
  **The file is not added**
- git config core.filemode true
  **File is still listed as unchanged**
- git rm --cached config
  **git shows file as deleted, but reports no change the the file after "git add config"**
- changed the permission bits and added an extra line in the file, committed that change, and pushed it
  **After pulling that change on another machine, the new blank line was present, but the new permissions were not propagated - they are still 664**

### Other Research

According to [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/How-can-I-force-git-to-recognize-a-change-change-in-file-modes-td2399103.html), Git will only recognize changes in the execution bit. I tested changing the execution bit, and git *does* recognize that change and would allow me to commit it. But I don't want the execute permission bit set.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git) recommends using [git-cache-meta](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/105133%7C%7CPATCH) to store permission bits besides the execution bit, but it looks like that solution requires modification of the remote server the repo is stored on, and I don't have control over that server.

I have consulted the following SO questions but they haven't helped:
[How to force Git to commit a file if it is recognized as unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666606/how-to-force-git-to-commit-a-file-if-it-is-recognized-as-unchanged)
[Updating file permissions only in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516201/updating-file-permissions-only-in-git)

There are also multiple questions about getting Git to *ignore* permission bit changes, but the answers pretty much all revolve around the filemode config option, which doesn't help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following question has the answer: [Git is changing my file's permissions when I push to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230171/git-is-changing-my-files-permissions-when-i-push-to-server)

So how can you update the file write permissions in the repository? You can't because read/write permissions aren't actually stored in the repository.

My suggestion would be to add a script that changes permissions after cloning the repository or if you have actions blocked by the current permissions add some code that changes the permissions before doing the actions.