# GIT only adds two lines of "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" file; it will not add/commit the whole file

Tags: git

I'm trying to add the most recent `jquery` file to my project's *static* folder, but, no matter what I do, it looks like only the following two lines get added:

```
/*! jQuery v3.3.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
!function(e,t){"use strict";"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=e.document?t(e,!0):function(e){if(!e.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return t(e)}:t(e)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(e,t){"use strict";var n=[],r=e.document,i=Object.getPrototypeOf,o=n.slice,a=n.concat,s=n.push,u=n.indexOf,l={},c=l.toString,f=l.hasOwnProperty,p=f.toString,d=p.call(Object),h={},g=function e(t){return"function"==typeof t&&"number"!=typeof t.nodeType},y=function e(t){return null!=t&&t===t.window},v={type:!0,src:!0,noModule:!0};function m(e,t,n){var i,o=(t=t||r).createElement("script");if(o.text=e,n)for(i in v)n[i]&&(o[i]=n[i]);t.head.appendChild(o).parentNode.removeChild(o)}function x(e){return null==e?e+"":"object"==typeof e||"function"==typeof e?l[c.call(e)]||"object":typeof e}var b="3.3.1",w=function(e,t){return new w.fn.init(e,t)},T=/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;w.fn=w.prototype={jquery:"3.3.1",constructor:w,length:0,toArray:function(){return o.call(this)},get:function(e){return null==e?o.call(this):e<0?this[e+this.length]:this[e]},pushStack:function(e){var t=w.merge(this.constructor(),e);return t.prevObject=this,t},each:function(e){return w.each(this,e)},map:function(e){return this.pushStack(w.map(this,function(t,n){return e.call(t,n,t)}))},slice:function(){return this.pushStack(o.apply(this,arguments))},first:function(){return this.eq(0)},last:function(){return this.eq(-1)},eq:function(e){var t=this.length,n=+e+(e<0?t:0);return this.pushStack(n>=0&&n<t?[this[n]]:[])},end:function(){return this.prevObject||this.constructor()},push:s,sort:n.sort,splice:n.splice},w.extend=w.fn.extend=function(){var e,t,n,r,i,o,a=arguments[0]||{},s=1,u=arguments.length,l=!1;for("boolean"==typeof a&&(l=a,a=arguments[s]||{},s++),"object"==typeof a||g(a)||(a={}),s===u&&(a=this,s--);s<u;s++)if(null!=(e=arguments[s]))for(t in e)n=a[t],a!==(r=e[t])&&(l&&r&&(w.isPlainObject(r)||(i=Array.isArray(r)))?(i?(i=!1,o=n&&Array.isArray(n)?n:[]):o=n&&w.isPlainObject(n)?n:{},a[t]=w.extend(l,o,r)):void 0!==r&&(a[t]=r));return a},w.extend({expando:"jQuery"+("3.3.1"+Math.random()).replace(/\D/g,""),isReady:!0,error:function(e){throw new Error(e)},noop:function(){},isPlainObject:function(e){var t,n;return!(!e||"[object Object]"!==c.call(e))&&(!(t=i(e))||"function"==typeof(n=f.call(t,"constructor")&&t.constructor)&&p.call(n)===d)},isEmptyObject:function(e){var t;for(t in e)return!1;return!0},globalEval:function(e){m(e)},each:function(e,t){var n,r=0;if(C(e)){for(n=e.length;r<n;r++)if(!1===t.call(e[r],r,e[r]))break}else for(r in e)if(!1===t.call(e[r],r,e[r]))break;return e},trim:function(e){return null==e?"":(e+"").replace(T,"")},makeArray:function(e,t){var n=t||[];return null!=e&&(C(Object(e))?w.merge(n,"string"==typeof e?[e]:e):s.call(n,e)),n},inArray:function(e,t,n){return null==t?-1:u.call(t,e,n)},merge:function(e,t){for(var n=+t.length,r=0,i=e.length;r<n;r++)e[i++]=t[r];return e.length=i,e},grep:function(e,t,n){for(var r,i=[],o=0,a=e.length,s=!n;o<a;o++)(r=!t(e[o],o))!==s&&i.push(e[o]);return i},map:function(e,t,n){var r,i,o=0,s=[];if(C(e))for(r=e.length;o<r;o++)null!=(i=t(e[o],o,n))&&s.push(i);else for(o in e)null!=(i=t(e[o],o,n))&&s.push(i);return a.apply([],s)},guid:1,support:h}),"function"==typeof Symbol&&(w.fn[Symbol.iterator]=n[Symbol.iterator]),w.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object Error Symbol".split(" "),function(e,t){l["[object "+t+"]"]=t.toLowerCase()});function C(e){var t=!!e&&"length"in e&&e.length,n=x(e);return!g(e)&&!y(e)&&("array"===n||0===t||"number"==typeof t&&t>0&&t-1 in e)}var E=function(e){var t,n,r,i,o,a,s,u,l,c,f,p,d,h,g,y,v,m,x,b="sizzle"+1*new Date,w=e.document,T=0,C=0,E=ae(),k=ae(),S=ae(),D=function(e,t){return e===t&&(f=!0),0},N={}.hasOwnProperty,A=[],j=A.pop,q=A.push,L=A.push,H=A.slice,O=function(e,t){for(var n=0,r=e.length;n<r;n++)if(e[n]===t)return n;return-1},P="checked|selected|async|autofocus|autoplay|controls|defer|disabled|hidden|ismap|loop|multiple|open|readonly|required|scoped",M="[\\x20\\t\\r\\n\\f]",R="(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\0-\\xa0])+",I="\\["+M+"*("+R+")(?:"+M+"*([*^$|!~]?=)"+M+"*(?:'((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'])*)'|\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\"|("+R+"))|)"+M+"*\\]",W=":("+R+")(?:\\((('((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\'])*)'|\"((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\\"])*)\")|((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\()[\\]]|"+I+")*)|.*)\\)|)",$=new RegExp(M+"+","g"),B=new RegExp("^"+M+"+|((?:^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\.)*)"+M+"+$","g"),F=new RegExp("^"+M+"*,"+M+"*"),_=new RegExp("^"+M+"*([>+~]|"+M+")"+M+"*"),z=new RegExp("="+M+"*([^\\]'\"]*?)"+M+"*\\]","g"),X=new RegExp(W),U=new RegExp("^"+R+"$"),V={ID:new RegExp("^#("+R+")"),CLASS:new RegExp("^\\.("+R+")"),TAG:new RegExp("^("+R+"|[*])"),ATTR:new RegExp("^"+I),PSEUDO:new RegExp("^"+W),CHILD:new RegExp("^:(only|first|last|nth|nth-last)-(child|of-type)(?:\\("+M+"*(even|odd|(([+-]|)(\\d*)n|)"+M+"*(?:([+-]|)"+M+"*(\\d+)|))"+M+"*\\)|)","i"),bool:new RegExp("^(?:"+P+")$","i"),needsContext:new RegExp("^"+M+"*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(
```

The whole file refuses to upload. I've tried `--force` to no avail. Might this have something to do with the fact that `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` is all on two lines? (What's uploaded to GIT is the whole first line, and a fraction of the second line). I'm not even sure how to begin debugging this!

My question is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666606/how-to-force-git-to-commit-a-file-if-it-is-recognized-as-unchanged). My problem is not that GIT doesn't recognize the file as being changed (I would have stated such if that were the case). My problems is that regardless of how I commit `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, whether or not I `git rm`, whether or not I rename it, move folders, etc.—only the above two lines are sent to GIT, not the whole file.

The two lines I posted above are the contents of the `diff` on the GIT UI (not the `diff` run locally). Someone pointed this out to me when reviewing my PR. The actual file is much longer than this, and continues on for many characters afterwards.

Comment: @bastos.sergio This is very clearly not a duplicate of that, and that solution **did not** work. Don't be so quick to jump the gun.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger StackOverflow is a huge bummer sometimes, man. Anyway, I edited my question a bit; GIT only shows part of the file in any pull requests, diffs, etc. (I was notified of this because someone reviewing my PR pointed out that the file ended prematurely)

Comment: What is the exact git version you're using?

Comment: @Amy `git version 2.7.4`

Comment: Point of clarification: you say it only adds two lines (`only the following two lines get added`), but later you say the file only contains one line (`jquery-3.3.1.min.js is all on one line`).  Can you clarify?  Which is it?  How many lines does the file have?

Comment: @Amy Sorry, that was a typo! `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` is all on *two* lines, not one—and only part of the 2nd line is sent. (I've edited the question appropriately)

Comment: I cannot reproduce using `Git 2.12.1.windows.1` and the file located at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js.

Comment: @Amy Hm. I wonder if this indicates it's something weird with the repository's settings

Comment: My gut tells me this is an issue with the viewer.  If you pull down a copy of the repository and inspect the file, is it incomplete?  It could be an issue with the diff viewer you're using, rather than Git itself.

Comment: @Amy Genius! Yes, that was exactly it. The viewer is not showing the full contents, but, upon cloning the repo. the full file is there. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your viewer is bugged?

I tested with `git version 2.12.1.windows.1` and the file located at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js.  I couldn't reproduce.

A few weeks ago I identified a similar issue using Sourcetree.  Sourcetree reported a file had only been partially committed.  By loading the Git repository website, I confirmed the file was fine, and Sourcetree was goofing up.

Your question is based on a reasonable assumption that may not be valid: that your viewer is displaying the file (or its diff) accurately.  *Is it?*

In situations like this, when things don't appear to make sense, I begin to challenge what I think I know by attempting to disprove each known "fact".  In this case, using a separate viewer to verify the first reveals to us that the file is committed just fine.  There is a problem, but it isn't located where we suspected, and the nature of the problem isn't what we suspected.

Git's working fine.  Your viewer is goofing up for some unknowable reason.

I hope this helps.